# Extending Aero Glass in F# (PInvoke)

Tags: f#, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm working on a F# console application. In the properties I set the output type of application to *Windows Application* to hide the console. I also created a form to run in its place. Currently I only have a simple form with no controls. To make the form I added referances to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` and opened them along with `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

The part that I don't know how to do is extending the aero-glass. There are loads of exaples on how to do it in C#. For example, here is the API call and MARGINS structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MARGINS
{
    public int cxLeftWidth;
    public int cxRightWidth;
    public int cyTopHeight;
    public int cyBottomHeight;
}
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
pubic static extend int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);
```

The API call from Form_Load event:

```
MARGINS margins = new MARGINS();
margins.cxLeftWidth = 0;
margins.cxRightWidth = 100;
margins.cyTopHeight = 0;
margins.cyBottomHeight = 0;
int result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref margins);
```

This is what I've got so far in F#:

The API call and MARGINS structure:

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type MARGINS =
    struct
        val cxLeftWidth : int
        val cxRightWidth : int
        val cyTopHeight : int
        val cyBottomHeigh t: int
        new(left, right, top, bottom) = { cxLeftWidth = left; cxRightWidth = right; cyTopHeight = top; cyBottomHeigh = bottom } (*Is there any other way to do this?*)
    end
[<DllImport("dwmapi.dll")>]
extend int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, (*I need help here*))
```

The API call from Form_Load event:

```
let margins = new MARGINS(0, 100, 0, 0); (*Is there any other way to do this?*)
let result : int = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, (*I need help here*))
```

I have been searching around but I can't find anything about using `ref` parameters like this in F#. I know this would be a lot easier to write in C# but the code behind the form will be easier to write int F# because it's a functional programing language and the whole program I'm writing is orientated around functions. I know this is purely decorative but please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, `extern` (AKA [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or platform invoke) definitions in F# use C-like syntax (and note that it's `extern`, not `extend`):

```
[<DllImport("dwmapi.dll")>]
extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(nativeint hWnd, MARGINS& pMarInset)
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
let mutable margin = ...
let result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, &margin)
```

Note that the way that you have defined `MARGINS` is not quite analogous to the C# definition.  The various `val` definitions are not mutable, and are actually properties rather than fields (though they're backed by fields, so it's probably not a big deal).  If you want them to be mutable fields, you can add the `mutable` keyword after `val` for each field:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type MARGINS =  
  val mutable cxLeftWidth : int        
  val mutable cxRightWidth : int        
  val mutable cyTopHeight : int        
  val mutable cyBottomHeight: int
```

(I've also used the `Struct` attribute instead of `struct ... end`, but that's just for brevity).  You can initialize this like you do in C#, or using F#'s named arguments:

```
let mutable margin = MARGINS(cxRightWidth = 100)
```

Comment: `[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]` From what I understand this is the default setting for structs, is that correct?

Comment: @KennethPosey - that's certainly true of C#, C++, and VB.NET (see the `LayoutKind` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx)).  Empirically, this also appears to be true of F#, but I don't think that's guaranteed by the spec.  In any case, I was just copying that part from the question itself.

Comment: Ok, I was just making sure my source (another stackoverflow comment) was accurant. Thanks!